# Enabling CascadeOnDelete for EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have attempted to set up CacadeOnDelete for our DB such that if you delete a `Folder`, all child Folders are then also deleted.

The `Folder` is setup like so

```
public class Folder
{
    [Key]
    public int FolderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Folder Parent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int ParentFolderId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Folder> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

And I have attempted to setup the cascading delete like so, but when I run this the database generation never completes, although I get no exceptions either

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Folder>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Devices)
        .WithMany(x => x.PresentInFolders);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Folder>()
        .HasOptional(f => f.Parent)
        .WithMany(f => f.Children)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.ParentFolderId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the declaration of your relation between `Folder` and `Folder`.

If I look on your model, you have a Folder with many Children, but a Folder have a unique Parent. However, you set a Many-to-Many relation in your model builder.

Try to create this relation :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Folder>()
    .HasOptional(f => f.Parent)
    .WithMany(f => f.Children)
    .HasForeignKey(f => f.ParentFolderId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

You have to add a ParentFolderId property on your Folder, and I think it will works. You can have a look on [this example from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#UniDirectional)

Hope it helps !

Comment: The doc for `WillCascadeOnDelete()` says `Configures cascade delete to be on for the relationship.` - Doesnt that indicate that not specifying a parameter will default to `true` anyway?

Comment: Update - I checked and passing in true doesnt make any difference

Comment: @Chris I have update my answer. I think the problem is on the declaration of your modelbuilder. Hope it works.

Comment: My folder can have many devices, and a device can be in more than one folder.  Separately a folder can have many Folder children (but a folder can only have one parent)